# django 'DateTimeField' has no default value error

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

i am novice at django development. i am creating a class A which might have multiple class B assigned to it:

```
class A(models.Model):        
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        self.name


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mydate = models.DateTimeField('party date')
```

When i am trying to create a new "A" element at the admin page, and creating a matching element B for it and then `save()` , i am getting the Warning:
**Field 'mydate' doesn't have a default value**

If i move the "mydate",element to class A, then when hitting `save()` i am getting a message **This field is require** from Django, requires me to fill the field!

how can i make this required message appear also when date field is part of B!!!

Thanks

Comment: You need to add more detail for a good answer here. How are you "creating a matching element B"? Is it done in `A`'s `save` method, as part of a `post_save` signal, or are you literally going to the admin add/change page for `B` and doing it from there? Depending on which method, the answer to your question could be wildly different.

Comment: yes i was trying to do this through A element save()! i don't know what is the post_save, however i assume its being called for each B i save together with A

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have not specified, that your field is optional, you will have to provide a value for it every time you create an object. In your case you can't so you will have to do one of those things:

Here is how to make field optional:

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mydate = models.DateTimeField('party date', blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is how you set the  default value:

```
import datetime

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mydate = models.DateTimeField('party date', default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Comment: i had to move to sqlit also to make it work! aditionaly to u'r proposal

Comment: @sramij, no need to change DB engine, you just had to recreate the database using `suncdb`.

Answer (score 4):

There's an utility function in Django

```
from django.utils import timezone
class B(models.Model):
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  mydate = models.DateTimeField('party date', default=timezone.now)
```

This function will return you a datetime object based on USE_TZ in settings.py

```
def now():
  """
  Returns an aware or naive datetime.datetime, depending on settings.USE_TZ.
  """
  if settings.USE_TZ:
      # timeit shows that datetime.now(tz=utc) is 24% slower
      return datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
  else:
      return datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, django will try validate model A and then return the validation errors. Since A validates, it tries to write A which fails since B doesn't validate. I'm not sure off hand how to do this elegantly, but if you try evaluate form B on its own before validating A you'll get the "this field is required" message which you can then display to the user.